# Como fazer uma trigger Delete com validações

Tags: mysql

Tenho o seguinte problema, quero que depois que eu delete uma locação da tabela locações eu vá na na tabela filmes e faça com que a coluna  situação fique como disponível, mas no caso se eu tiver o código do filme na tabela locações em outro registro, eu ainda deixe a coluna situação da tabela filme como locado, como eu faria isso?

isso é o que eu já fiz.

```
TRIGGER `tguDelete` AFTER DELETE ON `locacoes` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE filmes SET situacao = 'Disponivel' WHERE id_locacao = OLD.id_locacao
```

Essas são minhas tabelas

[image: tabela locações]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso phpmyadmin, e sou iniciante em mysql

Comment: Realmente é necessário o uso de trigger? Há uma aplicação consumindo esse banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, é meu trabalho de curso